# I uploaded my new profile picture in Movies.SE, but in other site it is not shown?

Tags: support, profile-page, profile-picture

I changed and uploaded a new profile picture of mine in Movies.SE, but the change is not reflected in other Stack Exchange sites, the previous picture is still retained. Do I have to change the picture one at a time for different sites? If so, it would be very problematic. Is there any way I can change the picture everywhere simultaneously?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pretty simple.

1. Go to your profile.
2. Click *edit*.

   > [image]
3. Change the profile picture.

   > [image]
4. Click <kbd>Save And Copy Profile To All Stack Exchange Accounts</kbd>

   > [image]

Comment: Concrete answer. +1 from me. :-)